# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier on strings with quotes and backticks

Tags: javascript

I have value from javascript here which is a json string.

```
<script>
  var data = '[{"text":"Lorem's ipsum dolor sit amet"},{"text":"consectetur`s adipiscing elit"}]';
  console.log(data);
</script>
```

The above code has error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

I also used backtick instead of single/double quote, but it has same error

```
<script>
  var data = `[{"text":"Lorem's ipsum dolor sit amet"},{"text":"consectetur`s adipiscing elit"}]`;
  console.log(data);
</script>
```

How can I do avoid the error? Given that the json string has single quote from `Lorem's` and backtick quote from `consectetur`?

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the single quote using backslash `\'`:

```js
var data = '[{"text":"Lorem\'s ipsum dolor sit amet"},{"text":"consectetur`s adipiscing elit"}]';
console.log(data);
```

Comment: But the data was coming from database, that just the text returned from API

Comment: You mean the javascript code is generated by a html preprocessor like php? @JSN

Comment: @JSN: If the text is coming from an API, how is it in your JavaScript *source code*? Is the source generated on the server side? The problem is only because the "text" is inside a string *literal*.

Comment: @JSN If that's the issue. The way you're passing data from server to client is completely wrong. This may cause serious security issues and expose your website to XSS vulneralbilities. Try get the data via sending a request to the server from the client though an API.

Comment: Ahh I see.. `The way you're passing data from server to client is completely wrong.` This is right. Thanks to your inputs @HaoWu

Answer (score 0):

You are not using consistent style backtick or single quote in the json, dont' mix them. for example wrap the whole json with backticks. now if you are wrapping with backticks then replace "consectetur`s..." with "consectetur's...".
below is your updated code

```js
var data = `[{"text":"Lorems's ipsum dolor sit amet"},{"text":"consectetur's adipiscing elit"}]`;

console.log(data);
```

Comment: I see.. it should not be mixed, I'll replace that one when saving the data to the database.. Thank you!

Comment: @JSN glad, glad to be of help:>

Comment: @JSN I would suggest keeping things simple with only double quotes and single quotes inside json, using backtick only for wrapping up the json

Comment: Okay, noted. Thank you!